# Formula to daily update master table based on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, formula, auto-update

I have one sheet where team leaders will daily input information.
Now I need to create new master sheets that will be updated daily based on the above mentioned.

So now, for instance, in my main sheet there is range M28:O30 where TLs can mark employees' satisfaction choosing ":)" or ":(".
In a new sheet I need to create table that will count daily the ":)" and ":(" adding new row with daily information each day. This is how the daily table looks like:

[image: Daily table, where TLs will be introducing data everyday]

And I would like to the data be summarized in such simple table:

[image: New Master table created based on Daily Table]

I did simple formula =COUNTIF but it doesn't create new row with data each date of course.

I am sure that it is doable with VBA but I was wandering if it was possible to achieve with formulas without going into coding. If I have to code, could someone help?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt that there would be a complete "non code" solution to this. But here is a very minimal solution, that could run once the TL closes the workbook.

Basically you'd have to prefill your 2nd sheet with the dates of this year (or whatever date range you want to include) and then fill column B4 all the way to end with this formula (note that I've called your master data sheet "Master"):

```
=IF($A4<>TODAY(),"",COUNTIF(Master!$M$28:$O$30,$B$3))
```

And for column C do the same thing but with

```
=IF($A4<>TODAY(),"",COUNTIF(Master!$M$28:$O$30,$C$3))
```

What this will do is it'll calculate the countif but only if it's the current day. So all later entries will show up empty. To keep the previous ones, we'll just need a short macro, that will copy the formula of the current day and paste it as values. Something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

 Call PasteValuesCurrentDay     'This will just call the macro before closing of the map

End Sub

Sub PasteValuesCurrentDay()

Dim yourWB As Workbook
Dim sf As Worksheet

Dim lr As Long, r As Long

Set yourWB = ThisWorkbook
Set sf = yourWB.Sheets("Satisfaction")  'I've called the worksheet with the table satisfaction

lr = sf.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row 'this will automatically give you the last row of your table

'loop through all entries of your table
For r = 4 To lr
    If sf.Range("A" & r) = Date Then    'if you find the entry for the current date then do something
        sf.Range("B" & r & ":C" & r).Copy               'Copy the values in B and C in the row with the current date
        sf.Range("B" & r).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues    'Paste it as values to prevent the formula result from changing the next day
    End If
Next r

yourWB.Save 'save because otherwise your macro will have ran for nothing

End Sub
```

You'd have to include this in the "ThisWorkbook" section of your workbooks vba code.

Comment: Dear MTrk,
Thank you so much, I was afraid that I would have to use coding, I am very noobish in VBA that is why I was trying to avoid it, but if it unavoidable then I am also good with VBA solution.
No I would like to ask you one more question.
Your solution requires prefilling column A with dates, unfortunately it might be a bit problematic as since different TLs working with different customers they also have different holidays, so there would be many unnecessary dates. 
As you can see in daily sheet N5:O5 are merged cells with =TODAY functions, would it be possible to alter the code

Comment: so that the Satisfaction table updates only when someone actually opens the Daily Table and changes the information there (I am aware that in that case it is doable ONLY with VBA);
I tried tens of combinations of IF, IFS, COUNTIFS formulas and unfortunately, at least to my knowledge, I did not find solution for that :(

Comment: I have tried your solution @MTrk, and when I run the Macro the message I get in cells is:

This cell is inconsistent with the column formula.

I guess it is because the macro saves the value of the formula as number and deletes the formula from the cell, am I correct?

But then I am just wandering if in that case the macro is needed at all? Could we not just leave the prefilled date column with two columns with formulas?